# Is it true: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{b_n}$&$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{c_n}$ are irrational=>$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{c_n}$ is irrational

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, irrational-numbers

Assume that the: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{b_n}$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{c_n}$$
are convergent and irrational, then if
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{c_n}$$ is convergent 
should it also be irrational then for the integer $a_n$, $b_n$ and $c_n$?

I assume this is false, but can not find any counterexample.

Comment: The $a_n$, $b_n$ and $c_n$ are integers.

Comment: Could you explain what led you to conjecture such a result?

Comment: If we consider the product of first and second sums if they are irrational this will give us some sum set of coefficients $\sum\frac{a_n}{b_n}\frac{b_{n-k}}{c_{n-k}}$. In the most of cases this will bring us to another irrational value except the cases with $\frac{1}{a}*a$. So I wanted to understand if the form of the sum is critical for the irrationality. So I started from the simplest case.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the fact that the values of a sequence are rational, resp. irrational, with the fact that their sum is rational, resp. irrational. Each of these four cases may happen, as simple examples show.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a_n = n+1, b_n = (-1)^n n(n+1), c_n = n(n+1)^2$

Then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = -\ln 2$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{b_n}{c_n} = \ln 2 -1$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{c_n} = 1$$

Comment: Amazing. Interesting to see that the sum of this three sums are 0.

Comment: These three sums give 0 is rather a coincidence I think, if you multiply $b_n$ by an arbitrary  integer, then the three sums no longer sum to 0.

Answer (score 4):

Another example with all terms positive is

$$ a_n = 2n+1, \qquad b_n = n(n+1)(2n-1), \qquad c_n = n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(2n+1). $$

Then we can prove that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{8}{3}\log 2, \qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{b_n}{c_n} = \frac{9}{15} - \frac{8}{15}\log 2, \qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{c_n} = \frac{1}{18}. $$

Comment: This is more non trivial example.

Comment: Very ingenious! I tried to construct positive examples like these but didn't come up with any.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} R(n)$ with a rational function $R(x)$ usually spits out polygamma functions, we have a rather large room for choosing sequences subject to $a_n/c_n$ having a special form.

Comment: Is it possible to find an example with different irrationality in the first and second sums. I mean the $\log 2$ and $\pi$ for example.